# MPGS Direct Payment 3DS cannot finalise payment

Tags: rest, mastercard

I'm Trying to make the payment with 3DS work, I have followed the three steps in this link:
https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/authentication/3DS/integrationModelAPI.html?locale=en_US

My Process:

- Create a Session (Successful)

  POST to "https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/71/merchant/TEST123456/session/"
- Update the session with card details (Successful)
- Initiate Authentication (Successful)[example code in steps link]
  https://cibpaynow.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/71/merchant/TEST123456/order/1/transaction/2
- Authenticate Payer (Successful)[example code in steps link]
- Proceed to payment (X)[example code in steps link]

So the issue at the last step, which I don't understand why does it happen, is when I run this, as mentioned in the steps with providing `order.id` and `authentication.trasanctionId`:

```
{
    "authentication" :
    {
        "transactionId": "2"
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "SESSION0002873236543L1392791G59"
   },
    "order":{
        "amount":"1",
        "currency":"EGP",
        "reference" : "1"
    },
    "apiOperation": "PAY",
    "transaction":{
        "reference":"1"
    }
}
```

This is the response I get, which makes no sense since it should be the same `transactionId` that I was authenticating:

```
{
    "error": {
        "cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
        "explanation": "A transaction with this transaction ID has already been processed but the request parameters do not match. To process a new transaction for this order, the transaction.id must be unique for the order."
    },
    "result": "ERROR"
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

========= EDIT ========

I May have concluded that it might be that I'm initiating a `PAYER_WEBSITE` authentication, and I'm PAYING through an API put request, I don't really know but this is my only explanation, if this is the issue how should I initiate an authentication that can be completed using a request that is not necessary to be from a web site.

Comment: Yes, The error message states that I'm running a new transaction and it cannot continue, but I'm still on the same transaction that I have initialised, so why does it not recognise this?